# print some indiviual forms together using visual studio repoter

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, reporting

I'm writing a program using c# and sql. I have some factors and want to print them separately but in one process with visual studio reporter(rdlc).
I can print them individualy now but I don't know how can I print all of them (or some of them) in one process.
thx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

First, you must write a query to select all data including buying items, quantity, ship names, order ids and etc in only one table and forget about the replication.
Then go to rdlc report and add a List to report body, List is a data region control so for every group of items, it will repeat. Now you must design your factor inside List.
After that, create a row group (look below the screen, in VS) and choose a Group on expression. (exp. OrderID) That is all.
You absolutely must use groups for a batch printing command, but the point is how to design the report and query together to get the proper result.